# Is it possible to use non-overlapping Series in zipline?

Tags: python, pandas, zipline

I need to use my own data for a zipline project.  I keep getting this error whenever I try:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zipline/sources/data_source.pyc in <dictcomp>((target, (mapping_func, source_key)))
     47         """
     48         row = {target: mapping_func(raw_row[source_key])
---> 49                for target, (mapping_func, source_key)
     50                in self.mapping.items()}
     51         row.update({'source_id': self.get_hash()})

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Here is the trading algorithm I am running:

```
from zipline.algorithm import TradingAlgorithm
from zipline.api import order_target, order, record, symbol, history, add_history
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
import pandas as pd

# Define algorithm
def initialize(context):
    context.dateIndex = 0

def handle_data(context, data):
    today = data.major_axis[context.dateIndex]

    if today > data.US9663871021[data.US9663871021.close.notnull()].index[0] and today < data.US9663871021[data.US9663871021.close.notnull()].last_valid_index():
        order(symbol('US9663871021'), 10)
        record(US9663871021=data[symbol('US9663871021')].price)
    if today > data.US7954351067[data.US7954351067.close.notnull()].index[0] and today < data.US7954351067[data.US7954351067.close.notnull()].last_valid_index():
        order(symbol('US7954351067'), 10)
        record(US7954351067=data[symbol('US7954351067')].price)

    if today == data.US9663871021[data.US9663871021.close.notnull()].last_valid_index():
        order_target(symbol('US9663871021'), 0)
        record(US9663871021=data[symbol('US9663871021')].price)
    if today == data.US7954351067[data.US7954351067.close.notnull()].last_valid_index():
        order_target(symbol('US7954351067'), 0)
        record(US9663871021=data[symbol('US7954351067')].price)    

    context.dateIndex = context.dateIndex + 1

def prepDf(fileName):
    df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(fileName, index_col=[0],parse_dates=[0], na_values=["#N/A N/A"],
                            names=["date", "open","high","low","close","volume","mkt_cap"])
    df["price"] = df.close
    df.index = df.index.tz_localize('UTC')
    df = df[df.close.notnull()]
    return df

fileName = #fill in file name
fileName2 = #fill in file name

dictionaryOfDfs = {"US9663871021" : prepDf(fileName), "US7954351067": prepDf(fileName2)}

data = Panel(dictionaryOfDfs)
algo_obj = TradingAlgorithm(initialize=initialize, 
                            handle_data=handle_data)

# Run algorithm
perf_manual = algo_obj.run(data)
```

The idea is that I'm buying when the data should be non-NaN and selling the position before the end of the series.  There should be no need for the data beyond that, yet zipline insists that NaN causes an error even when the value shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I believe the solution is to re-index the underlying DataFrames:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(index=data.major_axis, fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.reindex(index=data.major_axis, fill_value=0)
```

where data is the pandas Panel